# Grouping by using .net 2.0 how do you do it?

Tags: c#

Working on a .net 2.0 project and no linq and cannot add any external library.

Build a small example of what I need to do in my real project.

How do you group by eg "Employee.Category" without using linq.

For each group I need to do something about it.

How do you group by in .net 2.0?

```
     class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                List<Employee>employees=new List<Employee>();
                Employee employee = new Employee();
                employee.Id = 1;
                employee.Category = "Management";

                Employee employee2 = new Employee();
                employee.Id = 2;
                employee.Category = "Management";

                Employee employee3 = new Employee();
                employee.Id = 3;
                employee.Category = "Director";

                Employee employee4 = new Employee();
                employee.Id = 4;
                employee.Category = "Worker";

                Employee employee5= new Employee();
                employee.Id = 5;
                employee.Category = "Director";
                Employee employee6 = new Employee();
                employee.Id = 6;
                employee.Category = "Worker";

                employees.AddRange(new Employee[] { employee, employee2, employee3, employee4, employee5, employee6 });

                //1)Group them by category in .net 2.O NO LINQ
                //2)Foreach item in the group do something.

                Console.WriteLine("??");
            }
        }

        public class Employee
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Category { get; set; }
        }
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460309/c-list-group-by-without-linq

Comment: FYI - Jon Skeet has a series of blog articles on re-implementing LINQ to Objects which helps explain what all these methods actually do [Reimplementing LINQ to Objects](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/02/23/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-45-conclusion-and-list-of-posts.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
Dictionary<string, List<Employee>> groups =
       new Dictionary<string, List<Employee>>();
foreach(Employee emp in employees) {
    List<Employee> group;
    if(!groups.TryGetValue(emp.Category, out group)) {
        group = new List<Employee>();
        groups.Add(emp.Category, group);
    }
    group.Add(emp);
}

foreach(KeyValuePair<string,List<Employee>> pair in groups) {
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Key);
    foreach(Employee emp in pair.Value) {
        Console.WriteLine(emp.Id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Dictionary<TKey,List<TValue>>`.

```
foreach(var employee in employees)
{
  List<Employee> values;
  if(!dict.TryGetValue(employee.Category,out values))
  {
    values=new List<Employee>();
    dict.Add(employee.Category,values);
  }
  values.Add(employee);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Dictionary<string, List<Employee>>

```
Dictionary<string, List<Employee>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<Employee>>();

foreach(Employee e in employees)
{
    if(!dict.contains(e.Category))
        dict.Add(e.Category, new List<Employee()>);

    dict[e.Category].Add(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. If you want to change GroupBy, just use different GroupFieldDelegate.

```
    public delegate string GroupFieldDelegate(Employee e);

    private static string CategoryGrouping(Employee e)
    {
        return e.Category;
    }


    static Dictionary<string, List<Employee>> Group(List<Employee> Data, GroupFieldDelegate Grouping)
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<Employee>> result = new Dictionary<string, List<Employee>>();

        foreach (Employee e in Data)
        {
            string Category = Grouping(e);
            if (result.ContainsKey(Category)) result[Category].Add(e);
            else (result[Category] = new List<Employee>()).Add(e);c
        }
        return result;
    }
```