# Is it possible to group by a list without linq

Tags: vb.net, list

I have a list containing these items.

```
ID     TaskId     Purposecode    UserId     Time
1      1          915            421        7.0
2      1          915            421        7.0
3      1          915            421        7.0
4      4          912            421        7.0
```

How can i group by without using linq?

The goal is to get this

```
   TaskId     Purposecode    UserId     Time
       1          915            421        21.0 (uniqeID: 1,2,3)
       4          912            421        14.0 (uniqeID: 4,5)
```

The reason why, i am doing this in code, is because i need the unique IDs after group by for other reasons.

Comment: why can'y you use LINQ? what has that to do with your unique IDs in the result?

Comment: The company I work for, do not use linq

Comment: @Zaz Any reson for not using LINQ ?

Comment: I guess it is a problem of framework, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460309/c-sharp-list-group-by-without-linq

Answer (score 0):

You can take a dictionary of lists... like this (assuming "Item" is the entity with your data):

```
Dictionary<int, List<Item>> itemsByTask = new Dictionary<int, List<Item>>()
foreach (Item item in items) {
  List<item> groupItems;
  if (!itemsByTask.TryGetValue(item.TaskID, out groupItems)) {
    groupItems = new List<Item>();
    itemsByTask.add(item.TaskID, groupItems);
  }
  groupItems.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: @Vland, I hadn't noticed the tag - but since it is .NET and pretty much just about using library classes this can easily be translated into working VB.NET code. Be my guest and suggest an edit instead of downvoting...